# Why does memory latency increase significantly before reaching the memory bandwidth limit?

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture, amd-processor, memory-bandwidth

The CPU I am using is AMD 9654*2, with memory running at 4800MHz and a total of 24 channels. Therefore, theoretically, the memory bandwidth limit of the machine is 921.6GB/s (4800 * 8 * 24 / 1000).

However, when I tested the latency and bandwidth relationship using MLC, **I found that when the memory bandwidth exceeds 388GB/s (42.1% utilization), the memory latency increases significantly, impacting software performance**. When the memory bandwidth exceeds 700GB/s, the memory latency exceeds 1000ns, making the software completely unusable.

**Why does memory latency start to increase significantly when the memory bandwidth utilization is below 50%? Which aspect of hardware capability is this constraint coming from? Is it the CPU, MMU, DIMM, or DRAM?**

```
./mlc --loaded_latency

  Delay   (ns)    MB/sec
==========================
   00000  1135.83  736300.0
   00002  1147.45  736493.2
   00008  1150.77  736122.9
   00015  1149.88  734617.0
   00050  1181.60  734202.9
   00100  1123.81  734903.9
   00200  1112.25  734429.5 <= 
   00300  173.65   631984.1
   00400  155.37   480770.5
   00500  144.68   388157.8 <=
   00700  140.57   280308.7
   01000  140.71   197585.1
   01300  137.59   153031.9
   01700  136.29   117527.8
   02500  135.91    80356.0
   03500  134.87    57644.2
   05000  134.92    40557.2
   09000  134.71    22780.5
   20000  133.78    10525.7
```